# Why does removing the correct item in state array, not delete the right component in the UI? - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I console.log the index that is being deleted it shows the correct index to be deleted, but the behaviour does not correspond - it always only deletes the last item in the array on the UI. (but in the state array it is deleting the correct index)

example:
(*refer to image below*)
When I click on delete for the first item (index 0), it removes the last item (index 3) from the UI. But upon viewing the console.log, it actually removed the correct item (index 0) from the state array.

*How it looks in the UI:*

- Note that the red numbers are there just for me to know if the array index is correct. (and it is working correctly)

[image: How it looks like in the UI]
*EditUser.js*

```
// holds the array of data for each RoleMapInput component
const [roleMaps, setRoleMaps] = useState([{organisation:[], roles:[], type:[]}]);

// Used to add a RoleMapInput component to the UI
const handleAddRoleMap = () =>{
    setRoleMaps((oldRoleMaps) => [...oldRoleMaps,{organisation:[], roles:[], type:[]}])
}
// Used to delete a RoleMapInput component from the UI
const handleDelRoleMap = (delIndex) =>{
    console.log("delIndex: ", delIndex)
    setRoleMaps((oldRoleMaps) => {
      console.log(oldRoleMaps)
      return oldRoleMaps.filter((_,index)=>index !== delIndex)
})

...
...
...

return(

...

// Where the RoleMapInput component is duplicated based on the array roleMaps
{console.log("roleMaps at grid: ",roleMaps)}
{roleMaps.map((roleMap, index) => (
       <RoleMapInput key={index} roleMapIndex={index} roleMap={roleMap} handleDelRoleMap={handleDelRoleMap}/>
))}

...

)
```

*RoleMapInput.js*

```
export default function RoleMapInput(props) {

...
...

return (
    <>
      <Grid item xs={1}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <IconButton aria-label="delete" color='error' onClick={()=>props.handleDelRoleMap(props.roleMapIndex)}>
            {props.roleMapIndex}
            <DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon/>
          </IconButton>
        </FormControl>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the minimum reproducible example is really hard to tell. But I can tell you this: the filter function is working properly, but using as react docs mention:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

You can read more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

A possible explanation is that when you are removing the element on pos 0 react might consider that it doesn't need to re-render any child component, but rather remove the last element (because you had rendered `<RoleMapInput` components with keys `0,1,2,3` and after removing any item from the array you are left with keys `0,1,2`)